# How to save a file to a shared Windows directory?

Tags: android, c++, c++builder-xe7

When I compiled my program on Windows it perfectly saved a .txt file to the shared folder on my laptop. What I did next was starting the same code on Android which told me "Not a directory"!

```
Memo_NetworkSaveText->Lines->SaveToFile("\\\\My_LT\\e\\New.txt");
```

Do I have to change the path format or does android need another call?

Comment: It will not be possible unless you are in a controlled environment. But you can use services like dropbox to share files. Run it on both android and "My_LT".

Comment: Read the documentation: [Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)